# SendGrid Django Template tags returning HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: django, python-3.x, sendgrid

Having an annoying issue. I am using Django to send data to sendGrid templates. But when I add substitutions I get a HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.  If I dont add anything in the dictionary it works just fine emailing the template as expected. So I am sure the problem is in the tag format and I cant seem to find the correct combenation

Python

```
    def emailSendGrid(self):
    mail = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject="Your Subject from sendGrid",
        body="SendGrid sent This is a simple text email body.",
        from_email="anon@test",
        to=["dude@test"],
        headers={"Reply-To": "anon@test"}
    )
    # Add template
    mail.template_id = '#######################'

    # Replace substitutions in sendgrid template
    mail.substitutions = {'testTag': 'new content from Django'}


    fail_silently = False
    mail.send()
```

SendGrid Template

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>This is a test email template from sendGrid</h3>
  <p> -testTag- </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This should be really simple but I have tried so my combinations and googled it with no resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using curl post from Django. Hope this helps someone in the future. I also found a very nice curl code to python,php,R and node.js converter that also helped a lot. https://curl.trillworks.com/

```
import requests

headers = {
        'authorization': 'Bearer API_KEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    testData = 'This is new testing data'
    data = '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "to_email_Address"}], "dynamic_template_data": {"testTag": "My new data"}}],"from": {"email": "from_email"},"subject":"Hello, World!","content": [{"type": "text/plain","value": "Heya!"}] ,"template_id" : "TEMPLAT_ID"}'
```

Special thanx to dirkgroten for pointing me in the right direction.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252711/dirkgroten